# How can I paste a bitmap of an Excel chart using VSTO and C#

Tags: c#, excel, bitmap, vsto

I'm creating a GUI application using WPF and i have to display a picture of a chart generated in Excel in the GUI.

I Generate the chart in Excel using code similar to this, which works fine:

```
        ChartObjects charts = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1].ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        ChartObject chartObject = charts.Add(0, 0, 400,400);
        Chart chart = chartObject.Chart;

        // Set chart object properties
        chart.ChartType = XlChartType.XlChartType.xl3DBarClustered;
        SeriesCollection seriesCollection = (SeriesCollection)chart.SeriesCollection();

        var series = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
        series.Values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        series.XValues = new int[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
        series.Name = "MySeries";
        ChartArea chartArea = chart.ChartArea;
```

The result end up looking like this

[image]

I then copy the image to the clipboard using this code:

```
    ChartArea chartArea = chart.ChartArea;
    chartArea.Copy();
```

And paste it to my GUI using:

```
    BitmapSource bitmap = Clipboard.GetImage();
```

However, the result does not contain the axes, the chart title or the series name.

The result looks like this:

[image]

I've tried pasting the content of my clipboard into paint after running the method, and that results in a picture like the one i want, with axes and all. I suppose that means the problem occurs on the last line that returns the image from the clipboard.

Does anyone know how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in Clipboard.GetImage(), as explained and solved in the following article: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/02/05/wpf-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard/